# launch a folder in windows explorer with php

Tags: php, command

hi there i am trying to launch a folder in windows explorer but is dosent seem to work the code i am trying is

```
$contain_path = 'E:\Something\Some Folder';
$folder = '9999 - Some Folder Name Here';
$command = 'explorer "'.$contain_path.'\\'.$folder.'\\"';
system($command,$var);
```

i even tried, but didn't succeed with

```
system($command,$var);
```

Its just a local wampserver project. i am making it such that when i press a button. The ajax script call the php page and then php page executes the above code and then the explorer window pops up just like it does when i execute the command given above through command prompt. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't think this can work. The server isn't running from your username or within your login session, is it?

Comment: @Barmar I think with a WAMP setup it should. Don't think I've seen user accounts in play there. In linux it would fail. But hey, no explorer.exe there :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer to this problem. I am assuming that the PHP code will be running on a Windows PC. A possible situation would be if the user is running **WAMP** or a similar setup.

```
<?PHP

$file_location = 'C:\Users\User\Documents';
exec("start \"\" \"{$file_location}\"");

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

quickest guess would be that `explorer` should be `c:\windows\explorer.exe`

Comment: @MaSK what is $var actually ? Have you checked the error_log for any feedback?

Comment: $var always returns 1 don't know what that means. and error_log doesn't show and error. Is there a way i can do this through .bat file?

Comment: @MaSK please do `system($command . ' 2>&1',$var);` and then see what is in $var

Comment: its still 1. don't know whats going on

Comment: Then on second thought I tend to agree with Barmar. The problem being that your web server is probably running as a service in Session 0, and has *Session 0 isolation*.